# Out of memory when creating large number of relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4J, and I want to try it on some data I've exported from MySQL. I've got the community edition running with `neo4j console`, and I'm entering commands using the `neo4j-shell` command line client.

I have 2 CSV files, that I use to create 2 types of node, as follows:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/tmp/updates.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Update {update_id: row.id, update_type: row.update_type, customer_name: row.customer_name, .... });

CREATE INDEX ON :Update(update_id);

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/tmp/facts.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Fact {update_id: row.update_id, status: row.status, ..... }); 

CREATE INDEX ON :Fact(update_id);
```

This gives me approx 650,000 Update nodes, and 21,000,000 Fact nodes.

Once the indexes are online, I try to create relationships between the nodes, as follows:

```
MATCH (a:Update)
WITH a
MATCH (b:Fact{update_id:a.update_id})
CREATE (b)-[:FROM]->(a)
```

This fails with an `OutOfMemoryError`. I believe this is because Neo4J does not commit the transaction until it completes, keeping it in memory.

What can I do to prevent this? I have read about `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` but it appears this is only useful when reading the CSV, as it doesn't work in my case:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ USING PERIODIC COMMIT
> MATCH (a:Update)
> WITH a
> MATCH (b:Fact{update_id:a.update_id})
> CREATE (b)-[:FROM]->(a);
QueryExecutionKernelException: Invalid input 'M': expected whitespace, comment, an integer or LoadCSVQuery (line 2, column 1 (offset: 22))
"MATCH (a:Update)"
 ^
```

Is it possible to create relationships in this way, between large numbers of existing nodes, or do I need to take a different approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Out of Memory Exception is normal as it will try to commit it all at once and as you didn't provide it, I assume java heap settings are set as default (512m).

You can however, batch the process with kind of pagination, only I would prefer to use MERGE rather than CREATE in this case :

```
MATCH (a:Update)
WITH a
SKIP 0
LIMIT 50000
MATCH (b:Fact{update_id:a.update_id})
MERGE (b)-[:FROM]->(a)
```

Modify SKIP and LIMIT after each batch until your reach 650k update nodes.

Comment: You probably can use higher limits depending on your available memory.

Comment: That helps, thanks. BTW you only need to modify SKIP and keep LIMIT constant.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, but I need to create 8 relationships among 5 nodes. I don't think the above match-with-skip-limit would be optimal for so many relationships to create with batch process. Any suggestion how to do this more optimally ? Thanks in advance! @MichaelHunger